# Error when converting Bitmap to Iplimage

Tags: c++, .net

I have a .net bitmap that must be converted to Open Cv image

On the .net side I am doing the following :

```
 b = new Bitmap(@"C:\Projects\samples\alfarok.jpg");
 b = b.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
 Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height);
 BitmapData bmpData = b.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, b.PixelFormat);
 IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
 int stride = bmpData.Stride;
 int numBytes = b.Width * b.Height * 3;
 byte[] rgbValues = new byte[numBytes];
 for (int r = 0; r < bmpData.Height; ++r)
    Marshal.Copy(new IntPtr((int)ptr + stride * r), rgbValues, bmpData.Width * 3 * r, bmpData.Width * 3);
    wrapper.DetectDocumentPatter(b.GetHbitmap(), rgbValues,b.Width,b.Height, numBytes);
```

In umanaged I am receiving an HBITMAP handle and byte array. I'm trying to build the DIB image first, but an exception is usually thrown: `std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x004ffb6c`.

```
BITMAP bmp;
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
GetObject(b,sizeof(tagBITMAP),&bmp);
long dwcBihSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
long dwSize = dwcBihSize +(2>>bmp.bmBitsPixel) * sizeof(RGBQUAD) + ((bmp.bmBitsPixel * width) * height);
LPBITMAPINFO pDIB =(LPBITMAPINFO) new BYTE[dwSize]; // check this ! 
pDIB->bmiHeader.biSize = dwcBihSize;
pDIB->bmiHeader.biWidth = width; 
pDIB->bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
pDIB->bmiHeader.biBitCount = bmp.bmBitsPixel;
pDIB->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
pDIB->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
pDIB->bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 1000 ;
pDIB->bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 1000;
pDIB->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
pDIB->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
LPRGBQUAD lpColors =(LPRGBQUAD)(pDIB+pDIB->bmiHeader.biSize);
SetDIBColorTable(hdc,0,2>>bmp.bmBitsPixel * sizeof(RGBQUAD),lpColors);
int dibCols = 2>>pDIB->bmiHeader.biBitCount;
void* bitArray = pDIB + pDIB->bmiHeader.biSize+dibCols *sizeof(RGBQUAD);
for(int i=0;i<dibCols;i++)
{
  lpColors[i].rgbRed=0;
  lpColors[i].rgbBlue=0;
  lpColors[i].rgbGreen=0;
  lpColors[i].rgbReserved=0;
} 
SetDIBColorTable(hdc,0,dibCols,lpColors);
int depth =bmp.bmBitsPixel == 1 ? IPL_DEPTH_1U : IPL_DEPTH_8U;
int nChannels = 3;
//IplImage* image= cvCreateImage(cvSize(width,height),depth,3);
GetDIBits(hdc,b,0,height,bitArray,pDIB,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
//image->imageData = (char*)bitArray;
//memcpy(image->imageData,(char*)(bmp.bmBits),bmp.bmHeight*bmp.bmWidth*3);
//cvSaveImage("c:\img.jpg",image);
```

Am I doing things right, or is there a more suitable approach? Why might the error `std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x004ffb6c` be thrown?

Comment: Does `bitArray` contain the correct info throughout that array?  If not, double-check all portions of `bmiHeader` as a start.